# Arch Linux doesn't connect to a wireless network

Tags: networking, arch-linux, wifi, wicd

I'm using Arch Linux on a Thinkpad machine. Everything was satisfactory but today I restarted my router and the machine doesn't connect. The router is fine (another machine and a cell phone connect to it easily).

I'm using `wicd` from a terminal and all I get is a "not connected" message.

How can I fix/diagnose this?

*Edit*

I tried [this](http://wicd.sourceforge.net/punbb/viewtopic.php?id=277) without the script and replaced dhclient with dhcpcd (open network) and all I get is a connection time out.

Comment: I find wicd gets messed up sometimes. Try restarting wicd: `sudo /etc/rc.d/wicd restart`.

Comment: wicd has a log: to assist with diagnosis, see if there is any detail around the connection failing printed there...

Comment: What kind of connection is it, WEP, WPA?  
Have you tried using the netcfg scripts?

Comment: `dmesg` is also very talkative when it's about wireless errors.

Comment: What security settings are you using for your connection? WEP? WPA? WPA2? Have you tried turning these off to make sure it's an issue with wicd?

Answer (score 1):

Try checking that there is no dhcpcd stuck with a `sudo dhcpcd -k`. I get not connected errors when I first use my Android phone w/ tethering (for which I just run `sudo dhcpd` by hand) and then trying to use wifi .

Comment: Do you mean `sudo dhcpcd`?

Answer (score 0):

I have my Arch linux laptop get connected via a shell script.  This is for one of the WEP (I know, I know...) routers I use:

```
#!/bin/bash

DEV=$(iw dev | awk '/Interface/ {interf=$2} END {print interf}')
PIDFILE=/var/run/dhcpcd-$DEV.pid


if [[ -f $PIDFILE ]] && kill -0 $(cat /var/run/dhcpcd-$DEV.pid)
then
        dhcpcd -k $DEV
fi

ifconfig $DEV down
sleep 1
iwconfig $DEV mode managed
ifconfig $DEV up
iwconfig $DEV channel 1
iwconfig $DEV  key 4567ABCDEF
iwconfig $DEV essid 'ACTIONTEC'
iwconfig $DEV ap 00:0d:51:BF:FE:E1

sleep 5
dhcpcd --noarp $DEV
```

Every step does just one thing, so it's easy to figure out where the problem lies. The laptop used to run Slackware, under which I wrote the script, but it seems to work just fine under Arch as well.

Comment: Nice, a `set -e` at the top would make the script fail on the first failing command too :)

Answer (score -1):

I have used wicd on Arch in the past.  I stopped using it due to issues like this.  Try with NetworkManager/dhclient.